# Pointing python modules to install to a specified site-packages location

Tags: linux, python-3.x, pip, easy-install

I am having an issue when it comes to installing python3.3 modules.  The current modules are installing to /usr/lib64/python3.3/site-packages but they need to be installed to /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages.  Is there a way to point the installation to put the modules in the appropriate location?

I am using CentOS 6.6

Answer (score 1):

While you *could* specify a prefix directory to tell pip to install into a specific place:

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/" my_module
```

I would instead heavily recommend learning about and using [virtual environments](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) to give you greater control of your Python programming environment.

The creation and activation of a virtual environment looks like this:

```
pyvenv-3.4 my_new_environment
source my_new_environment/bin/activate
pip install my_module
```

which will make my_module install reliably inside of `my_new_environment`.

Whenever you want to "activate" this environment, you simply `source` the `activate` script to tell the `Python` interpreter where to find its libraries!